# makegrid equivalent in cartopy, moving from basemap to cartopy

Tags: python-3.x, projection, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

So, I have been using Basemap for years in Python 2.7, I am moving to Python3.7 and would like to move to cartopy.  I work with a lot of data where I have the projection info but I don't have lat and lon grids of the data.  This is how I would handle things in Basemap.

```
m=Basemap(
    llcrnrlon=-118.300,
    llcrnrlat=20.600,
    urcrnrlon=-58.958,
    urcrnrlat=51.02,
    projection='lcc',
    lat_1=38.,
    lat_2=38.,
    lon_0=-95.,
    resolution ='l',
    area_thresh=1000.
)
mwidth =  1008 #for 163 5km AWIPS2 grid
mheight = 722  #for 163 5km AWIPS2 grid
```

So I have setup the reference grid 'm' in Basemap...
Then to plot the data...I use this:

```
lons,lats=m.makegrid(mwidth,mheight)
x,y=m(lons,lats)
```

I can then use contourf or pcolormesh like this:

```
m.contourf(x,y,data)
```

I am basically looking for an equivalent in cartopy or pyproj or osgeo.  I want to pass projection information with the size of the grid and get lat/lons so I can plot with cartopy.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Use `numpy.meshgrid()` and be happy.

Answer (score 4):

The [makegrid docs](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.makegrid) state that it returns lats and lons which are equally spaced in the projected coordinate system. I imagine you mostly use this to put projected data onto any map by letting basemap give you the lat/lon locations. Cartopy operates in quite a different way, in that you are perfectly allowed to specify the coordinate system of your coordinates in the native coordinate system.

So, if you know your data's coordinates in `lcc` (Lambert Conformal Conic) then you can pass those through to cartopy, which will reproject it for you as appropriate:

```
xs = np.linspace(llc_x0, llc_x1, n_xs),
ys = np.linspace(llc_y0, llc_y1, n_ys),
plt.contourf(xs, ys, data, transform=ccrs.LambertConformalConic())
```

In effect, you don't actually *need* to talk lons/lats in order to be able to draw your data.

In some rare situations you only know lats/lons, even if the data is projected in another space. Cartopy deals with this with:

```
plt.contourf(lons, lats, data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Finally, if you have a bounding box in projected space, but the bounding box corners are in lon/lat then you can simply transform the corners then use linspace. The following (untested) code should do the trick:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

llc = ccrs.LambertConformal()

width = 20
height = 25
llcrnrlon=-118.300
llcrnrlat=20.600
urcrnrlon=-58.958
urcrnrlat=51.02

lons = np.array([llcrnrlon, urcrnrlon])
lats = np.array([llcrnrlat, urcrnrlat])

projected_corners = llc.transform_points(
    ccrs.PlateCarree(), lons, lats)

xs = np.linspace(
    projected_corners[0, 0], projected_corners[1, 0], width)
ys = np.linspace(
    projected_corners[0, 1], projected_corners[1, 1], height)
```