# Moving from basemap to cartopy

Tags: python-3.x, projection, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I am trying to move from Basemap in python2 to cartopy in python3. However, I am finding it difficult to transform some Basemap code block to cartopy:

Basemap (python2.7)

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
bmap = Basemap(projection='merc', resolution='c', llcrnrlon=-125, llcrnrlat=26, urcrnrlon=-56, urcrnrlat=46)

print bmap.makegrid(4, 4)[0]
[[-125. -102.  -79.  -56.]
 [-125. -102.  -79.  -56.]
 [-125. -102.  -79.  -56.]
 [-125. -102.  -79.  -56.]]

print bmap.makegrid(4, 4)[1]
[[26.         26.         26.         26.        ]
 [33.23223798 33.23223798 33.23223798 33.23223798]
 [39.91267019 39.91267019 39.91267019 39.91267019]
 [46.00000132 46.00000132 46.00000132 46.00000132]]
```

cartopy (python 3.7)

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
mrc = ccrs.Mercator()
lons = np.array([-125, -56])
lats = np.array([26, 46])
width = 4
height = 4
projected_corners = mrc.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), lons, lats)
xs = np.linspace(
    projected_corners[0, 0], projected_corners[1, 0], width)
ys = np.linspace(
    projected_corners[0, 1], projected_corners[1, 1], height)
print(xs)
[-14248894.82153902  -6567849.95680314]
print(ys)
[2736034.98592771 6413524.59416364]
```

Note: I am trying to follow steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53873435/makegrid-equivalent-in-cartopy-moving-from-basemap-to-cartopy) using Mercator projection to get behavior similar to makegrid but the result does not match with Basemap as seen above.

Comment: Please show all your code. I suspect that you missed some important steps.

Comment: I am looking for cartopy equivalents of individual blocks. Separated the statements to make that clear. Thanks.

Comment: @swatchai: Added missing code. Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate ` the result does not match with Basemap`. show the result you obtained, and what you expect.

Comment: @swatchai:Added a code sample to elaborate the mismatch. Thanks for your time.

Comment: In your examples BM makes a grid in geographical coordinates, CP projects a set of geographical coordinates into a cartographic system of reference.  Each library performs as instructed.

Comment: @gboffi: Can you suggest how I can achieve behavior of makegrid using cartopy?

Comment: If I understand Basemap docs, `bmap.makegrid(4, 4, returnxy = True)` does (also) what is done by Cartopy, the other way around I'd say that one has to convert back to geographical cooordinates, it's a matter of looking into Cartopy's docs...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The results are in good agreement if compared on the same basis (coordinate system). Here is the runnable code and the results:

```
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mrc = ccrs.Mercator()
lons = np.array([-125, -56])
lats = np.array([26, 46])
width = 4
height = 4
projected_corners = mrc.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), lons, lats)
xs = np.linspace(projected_corners[0, 0], projected_corners[1, 0], width)
ys = np.linspace(projected_corners[0, 1], projected_corners[1, 1], height)
x2d, y2d = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)

ax = plt.axes(projection = mrc)
ax.coastlines()
ax.scatter(x2d, y2d)
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

Output plot:

[image]

And the computation for coordinates (long, lat) of the grid points:

```
platecarr = ccrs.PlateCarree()
lon_lat_list = platecarr.transform_points(ccrs.Mercator(), xs, ys)
print(lon_lat_list)

[[-125.           26.            0.        ]
 [-102.           33.23738591    0.        ]
 [ -79.           39.91736844    0.        ]
 [ -56.           46.            0.        ]]
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help.